# Inserting an Ajax array into a date range picker

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, daterangepicker

I already got a lot of help regarding this project from the community but I need a bit more. I have a Javascript date range picker that I need to insert an Ajax array into from a MySQL database, but for some reason it's not working. Here is my code:

file #1 getdaterangepicker.php

```
   <?php
include 'dbconfig.php';

$sql="SELECT start_date, end_date FROM date_ranges ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

// Create empty array.
$date_ranges = array();

// Add every row to array;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    // Create an associative array to store the values in.
    // This will later be a JavaScript Object.
    array_push($date_ranges, array(
        'start'   => $row['start_date'],
        'end'     => $row['end_date']
    ));

    mysqli_close($conn);

} 

// Send the $date_ranges as JSON.
$json = json_encode($date_ranges); // '[{"start": "2019-08-18", "end": "2019-08-19"}]'
echo $json;
?>
```

file 2 index.php:

```
// AJAX request wrapper function.
// Call this function to get the dates from the server.
function getDateRanges(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getdaterangepicker.php',       // Change this to the uri of your file
        method: 'GET',                 // Use the GET method
        dataType: 'html',              // Expect a JSON response
        success: function(response) {  // What will happen when the request succeeds
            if (response) {            // Check if there is a response
                callback(response);    // Pass the response into the callback
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
getDateRanges(function(dates) {

    $('input[name="start_date"]').daterangepicker({
        autoUpdateInput: false,
        locale: {
            cancelLabel: 'Clear'
        },
        isInvalidDate: function(date) {
            // Here use your dates that you've got from the server.
            var dateRanges = [dates];
                        console.log(dates);
            return dateRanges.reduce(function(bool, range) {
                return bool || (date >= moment(range.start) && date <= moment(range.end)); 
            }, false);
        }
    });

    $('input[name="start_date"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        document.getElementById("start_date").value = picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
        document.getElementById("end_date").value = picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    });

    $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        $(this).val('');
    });

});
```

It should work, the javascript console outputs the correct array (`[{"start":"2019-08-20","end":"2019-08-25"}]`) but the date picker it's self isn't crossing off the invalid dates, however if I go into the code and replace `var dateRanges = [dates];` with `var dateRanges = [{"start": "2019-08-25", "end": "2019-08-31"}];` it works perfectly, as expected. What gives? Any ideas? The date range picker is from here: http://www.daterangepicker.com

Comment: Isn't `dates` already an array? What happens with `var dateRanges = dates;`

Comment: @Nick - I don't follow?

Comment: You're creating an extra level of array with `var dateRanges = [dates];` I think you just need `var dateRanges = dates;`

Comment: When I do that I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: dateRanges.reduce is not a function

Comment: Ah - `dates` is a string, not an array. You also need to change `dataType: 'html'` to `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: Make that an answer and I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. The main one is that the `dataType` on your ajax request is `html`, when it should be `json`. Because it is `html`, `dates` ends up being a string. Once this is corrected, `dates` will be an array as required, and then you can assign it to `dateRanges` directly without adding a nesting level i.e.

```
var dateRanges = dates;
```